# Outlook responsive Image in table not working / outside table is working

Tags: image, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm working in a responsive newsletter and I'm nearly finished. In the last two weeks I read about the issues and things to mess when coding a responsive newsletter.

My newsletter is ready to use and responsive but now I face some problem that I cant solve since two days.

I got an image that is responsive in Outlook:

```
<img src="#" style="width:230px;max-width:96%;border:0px;" width="230">
```

and a table that is also responsive in Outlook:

```
<table width="800" style="width:800px;max-width:96%;text-align:justify;font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:14px;line-height:1.2em;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:justify;font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:14px;line-height:1.2em;">
                    MASS-TEXT
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

so far so good - it works great. BUT if I put the image in the table it isn't responsive anymore:

```
<table width="800" style="width:800px;max-width:96%;text-align:justify;font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:14px;line-height:1.2em;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:justify;font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:14px;line-height:1.2em;">     
                    <img src="#" style="width:230px;max-width:96%;border:0px;" width="230">

    </td>
</tr>
```

Anybody know a solution for this or know why it isn't working because it works as single elements?

I tried a few things like give the rows and columns a percentage width and so on... nothing working. I just want a responsive table with a responsive image inside working for outlook... someone experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Dont you think that the **max-width** should be static and **width** should be relative i.e. max-width:800px and width:96%;

Comment: thx for your answer but outlook cant handle percentage width on tables.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works well in the standard outlook version. Outlook responsive Image in table working.

```
  <table width="600" >
    <tr><td>
      <img src="add image link"/>
    </tr></td>
  </table>
```

Comment: <table width="600" >

  <tr><td>
    
      <img src="add image link"/>

  </tr></td>

</table>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).